# Size.Width and Size.Height showing incorrect dimensions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So for I made .net winform and set its size to `600 by 600` in its properties in the Designer. Although when I do a `Debug.WriteLine(Width.Height)` and `Debug.WriteLine(Width.Height)` it comes out as `452 by 488`. How can this be the case?

Comment: Also: Is your application dpi aware?

Comment: That's pretty normal, your monitor resolution is set to 125%.  If you don't want the DPI virtualization feature to rescale the window then you have to declare your app [to be dpiAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034).  Just keep in mind that what you see now is what a user will see who runs their monitor at 100%.  Use VS2017 or later to design at 100%